# Why am I getting different results with the same code as someone else?

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

I've been struggling with with this project from K.N. King's *C Programming: A Modern Approach* for a while now. The book instructs to write a simple reverse polish notation evaluator using a stack. "Use`scanf(" %c", &ch)`
 to read the operators and operands" instructs the book, but I think it is ridiculous and unrealistic to write an evaluator that can only evaluate single digit integers, so I used `float` values for the operands and `char` values for the operators.

My problem is that the program skips every other operator `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'`, or `'/'` starting with the first one. It doesn't do this for `'='`, nor does it do it for the `float` operands. From what I know about `scanf` this shouldn't be happening - can you please explain this phenomenon to me?

Edit: Well, it seemed that this code worked reasonably well for Jonathan Leffler below, now I'm confused as to why it would work for him, but not for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h"

float read_expression(void);

int main(void)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("Enter an RPN expression: ");
        printf("\nValue of expression: %.4f\n", read_expression());
    }
}

float read_expression(void)
{
    while(scanf("\n")==false)
    {

        float operand, op1, op2;
        char ch;

        if (scanf(" %f", &operand))
        {
            push(operand);
            continue;
        }

        else 
        {
            scanf(" %c", &ch);

            switch (ch)
            {
                case '+':
                    op2=pop();
                    op1=pop();
                    push(op1+op2);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    op2=pop();
                    op1=pop();
                    push(op1-op2);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    op2=pop();
                    op1=pop();
                    push(op1*op2);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    op2=pop();
                    op1=pop();
                    push(op1/op2);
                    break;
                case '=': return pop();
                default: exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }

    }
}

void stack_underflow(void)
{
    printf("\nNot enough operands in expression\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void stack_overflow(void)
{
    printf("\nExpression is too complex\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

In case you want to execute this code, here is the included stack.h file:

```
#include<stdbool.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 100

void stack_overflow(void);
void stack_underflow(void);

float contents[STACK_SIZE];
int top=0;

void make_empty(void)
{
    top=0;
}

bool is_empty(void)
{
    return top==0;
}

bool is_full(void)
{
    return top == STACK_SIZE;
}

void push(float i)
{
    if (is_full())
        stack_overflow();
    else
        contents[top++]=i;
}

float pop(void)
{
    if (is_empty())
        stack_underflow();
    else
        return contents[--top];
}
```

Edit:
Here is the output when I compile and execute Jonathan Leffler's rpn61.c below, using gcc 7.1.1-4 and clang 4.0.1-5 on my machine which is an Arch linux vm.

```
[lyle@ARCHnix chapter10]$ ./proj6
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 3 4 5 + + + + =

Value of expression: 12.0000                                                                                                                                  
Enter an RPN expression: g
[lyle@ARCHnix chapter10]$ clang rpn61.c -o rpn61
[lyle@ARCHnix chapter10]$ ./rpn61
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 3 4 5 + + + + =
4.000000 + 5.000000 = 9.000000
3.000000 + 9.000000 = 12.000000
Result = 12.000000

Value of expression: 12.0000
Enter an RPN expression: g
Unexpected operator g
[lyle@ARCHnix chapter10]$ gcc rpn61.c -o rpn61
[lyle@ARCHnix chapter10]$ ./rpn61
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 3 4 5 + + + + =
4.000000 + 5.000000 = 9.000000
3.000000 + 9.000000 = 12.000000
Result = 12.000000

Value of expression: 12.0000
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 + =
Result = 2.000000

Value of expression: 2.0000
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 + + =
1.000000 + 2.000000 = 3.000000
Result = 3.000000

Value of expression: 3.0000
Enter an RPN expression: g
Unexpected operator g
```

Comment: Can you include an example of an expression that doesn't work? I just did `3 4 5 6 + + + =` and `3 4 + 5 6 +` and didn't see any problems. I also tried `3 4 +5 6 + + =` and got 15, but this makes sense if you consider +5 to be the operand, which scanf will.

Comment: well, for me `1 2 3 4 5 + + + + =` returns 12, with similar results for other inputs. If I enter a singular operator like `3 4 + =` it ignores it and just pops back out the last `float` variable pushed.

Comment: What platform/compiler/standard C library are you using?

Comment: I'm curious: why is the stack of type `int` when `read_expression()` returns a `float`?

Comment: Just a mistake on my part, I corrected it, but it didn't affect the program execution.

Comment: It only affected me when I tried to use `355 113 / =` to show an approximation to π and it printed `3.0000` instead of `3.1416`.  As you say, not a biggie.  FWIW: I was testing on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 with GCC 7.2.0.

Comment: There's also a semantic error. A `.h` file really shouldn't **define** external variables, just declare them.

Comment: Just a thought, are you sure you are running the code you think you are?  A `PATH` entry might not be doing what you think it is.  Try running the compiled program with the explicit full path name.

Answer (score 1):

I made some minor modifications to the code so that it could be compiled as a single file, and added basic debug printing, and change the stack type from `int` to `float`.  With those changes, I can't reproduce the claimed problems.

#### Code (`rpn61.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
// #include "stack.h"

void make_empty(void);
bool is_empty(void);
bool is_full(void);
void push(float i);
float pop(void);

float read_expression(void);

int main(void)
{
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        printf("Enter an RPN expression: ");
        printf("\nValue of expression: %.4f\n", read_expression());
    }
}

float read_expression(void)
{
    while (scanf("\n") == false)
    {
        float operand, op1, op2;
        char ch;

        if (scanf(" %f", &operand))
        {
            push(operand);
        }
        else
        {
            scanf(" %c", &ch);

            switch (ch)
            {
            case '+':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f + %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 + op2);
                push(op1 + op2);
                break;
            case '-':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f - %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 - op2);
                push(op1 - op2);
                break;
            case '*':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f * %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 * op2);
                push(op1 * op2);
                break;
            case '/':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f / %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 / op2);
                push(op1 / op2);
                break;
            case '=':
                op1 = pop();
                printf("Result = %f\n", op1);
                return op1;
                //return pop();
            default:
                printf("Unexpected operator %c\n", ch);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

#define STACK_SIZE 100

_Noreturn void stack_overflow(void);
_Noreturn void stack_underflow(void);

void stack_underflow(void)
{
    printf("\nNot enough operands in expression\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void stack_overflow(void)
{
    printf("\nExpression is too complex\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

float contents[STACK_SIZE];
int top = 0;

void make_empty(void)
{
    top = 0;
}

bool is_empty(void)
{
    return top == 0;
}

bool is_full(void)
{
    return top == STACK_SIZE;
}

void push(float i)
{
    if (is_full())
        stack_overflow();
    else
        contents[top++] = i;
}

float pop(void)
{
    if (is_empty())
        stack_underflow();
    else
        return contents[--top];
}
```

#### Sample output

```
$ rpn61
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 3 4 5 + + + + =
4.000000 + 5.000000 = 9.000000
3.000000 + 9.000000 = 12.000000
2.000000 + 12.000000 = 14.000000
1.000000 + 14.000000 = 15.000000
Result = 15.000000

Value of expression: 15.0000
Enter an RPN expression:  3 4 + =
3.000000 + 4.000000 = 7.000000
Result = 7.000000

Value of expression: 7.0000
Enter an RPN expression: 3 4 5 6 + + + = 
5.000000 + 6.000000 = 11.000000
4.000000 + 11.000000 = 15.000000
3.000000 + 15.000000 = 18.000000
Result = 18.000000

Value of expression: 18.0000
Enter an RPN expression: 3 4 + 5 6 + 
3.000000 + 4.000000 = 7.000000
5.000000 + 6.000000 = 11.000000
=
Result = 11.000000

Value of expression: 11.0000
Enter an RPN expression: =
Result = 7.000000

Value of expression: 7.0000
Enter an RPN expression:  3 4 + 5 6 +
3.000000 + 4.000000 = 7.000000
5.000000 + 6.000000 = 11.000000
=
Result = 11.000000

Value of expression: 11.0000
Enter an RPN expression: 11.11111 +=
7.000000 + 11.111110 = 18.111111
Result = 18.111111

Value of expression: 18.1111
Enter an RPN expression: 355 113 /
355.000000 / 113.000000 = 3.141593
q
Unexpected operator q
$
```

#### TL;DR

I cannot reproduce your problem...

#### More debug (`rpn67.c`):

This code has more debug information.  In particular, there's a function `dump_stack()` to dump the information on the stack, and the code reports on operands and operators as they are read.  I still can't reproduce your problem, sadly.

I'm wondering if the `scanf(" %f", &operand)` is consuming the `+` operators.  It shouldn't, but it might perhaps be an explanation for what's going wrong.  This might be revealed by seeing what the operators are as they're read.  Is it only `+` and `-` that go missing, or do you have an sequence with `*` or `/` (and not `+` or `-`) that goes wrong too?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
// #include "stack.h"

void make_empty(void);
bool is_empty(void);
bool is_full(void);
void push(float i);
float pop(void);
static void dump_stack(void);

float read_expression(void);

int main(void)
{
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        printf("Enter an RPN expression: ");
        printf("\nValue of expression: %.4f\n", read_expression());
        dump_stack();
    }
}

float read_expression(void)
{
    while (scanf("\n") == false)
    {
        float operand, op1, op2;
        char ch;

        if (scanf(" %f", &operand))
        {
            printf("NUmber: %f\n", operand);
            push(operand);
            dump_stack();
        }
        else
        {
            if (scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Operator scan failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Operator: %c\n", ch);
            dump_stack();

            switch (ch)
            {
            case '+':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f + %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 + op2);
                push(op1 + op2);
                break;
            case '-':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f - %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 - op2);
                push(op1 - op2);
                break;
            case '*':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f * %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 * op2);
                push(op1 * op2);
                break;
            case '/':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f / %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 / op2);
                push(op1 / op2);
                break;
            case '=':
                op1 = pop();
                printf("Result = %f\n", op1);
                return op1;
                //return pop();
            default:
                printf("Unexpected operator %c\n", ch);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

#define STACK_SIZE 100

_Noreturn void stack_overflow(void);
_Noreturn void stack_underflow(void);

void stack_underflow(void)
{
    printf("\nNot enough operands in expression\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void stack_overflow(void)
{
    printf("\nExpression is too complex\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

float contents[STACK_SIZE];
int top = 0;

void make_empty(void)
{
    top = 0;
}

bool is_empty(void)
{
    return top == 0;
}

bool is_full(void)
{
    return top == STACK_SIZE;
}

void push(float i)
{
    if (is_full())
        stack_overflow();
    else
        contents[top++] = i;
}

float pop(void)
{
    if (is_empty())
        stack_underflow();
    else
        return contents[--top];
}

static void dump_stack(void)
{
    printf("Stack (%d): Top", top);
    for (int i = top; i > 0; i--)
        printf(" %f", contents[i-1]);
    printf(" Bottom\n");
}
```

#### Sample output

```
$ rpn67
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 3 4 5 + + + + =
NUmber: 1.000000
Stack (1): Top 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 2.000000
Stack (2): Top 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 3.000000
Stack (3): Top 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 4.000000
Stack (4): Top 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 5.000000
Stack (5): Top 5.000000 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
Operator: +
Stack (5): Top 5.000000 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
4.000000 + 5.000000 = 9.000000
Operator: +
Stack (4): Top 9.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
3.000000 + 9.000000 = 12.000000
Operator: +
Stack (3): Top 12.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
2.000000 + 12.000000 = 14.000000
Operator: +
Stack (2): Top 14.000000 1.000000 Bottom
1.000000 + 14.000000 = 15.000000
Operator: =
Stack (1): Top 15.000000 Bottom
Result = 15.000000

Value of expression: 15.0000
Stack (0): Top Bottom
Enter an RPN expression: q
Operator: q
Stack (0): Top Bottom
Unexpected operator q
$
```

## Reproduction!

Ubuntu 16.04 VM running on a Mac, `rpn67` produces:

```
$ rpn67
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 3 4 5 + + + + =
NUmber: 1.000000
Stack (1): Top 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 2.000000
Stack (2): Top 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 3.000000
Stack (3): Top 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 4.000000
Stack (4): Top 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 5.000000
Stack (5): Top 5.000000 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
Operator: +
Stack (5): Top 5.000000 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
4.000000 + 5.000000 = 9.000000
Operator: +
Stack (4): Top 9.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
3.000000 + 9.000000 = 12.000000
Operator: =
Stack (3): Top 12.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
Result = 12.000000

Value of expression: 12.0000
Stack (2): Top 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
Enter an RPN expression: q
Operator: q
Stack (2): Top 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
Unexpected operator q
$
```

There's the problem on display.  We have a discrepancy between the Linux and BSD/macOS versions of `scanf()`.

There might even be some justice in the Linux implementation.  It looks at most one character ahead, so it reads the `+` as a valid possible start, then finds a blank, realizes that's not valid as a number, and the conversion fails, but only the space and not the `+` is is pushed back.

So, you're going to need a different mechanism in place of `if (scanf(" %f", &operand))` to read the operand.

## Resolution

There are many ways to 'fix' the problem.  The code below is hacky but more or less does the job.  A better solution would redesign the interface to `read_expression()` so that it returned both a status and the evaluated expression.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
// #include "stack.h"

void make_empty(void);
bool is_empty(void);
bool is_full(void);
void push(float i);
float pop(void);
static void dump_stack(void);

float read_expression(void);

int main(void)
{
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        printf("Enter an RPN expression: ");
        printf("\nValue of expression: %.4f\n", read_expression());
        dump_stack();
    }
}

static inline bool is_operator(char c)
{
    return (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '=' || c == '.' || c == 'q');
}

static bool get_token(size_t buflen, char buffer[buflen])
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && isspace((unsigned char)c))
        ;
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < buflen - 1; i++)
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                buffer[i] = '\0';
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("EOF detected\n");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (isspace(c))
        {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            return true;
        }
        else if (isdigit(c) || is_operator(c))
        {
            buffer[i] = c;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid character %c\n", c);
            buffer[i] = '\0';
            return false;
        }
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    return false;
}

float read_expression(void)
{
    char buffer[64];
    while (get_token(sizeof(buffer), buffer))
    {
        float operand;

        if (sscanf(buffer, " %f", &operand))
        {
            printf("NUmber: %f\n", operand);
            push(operand);
            dump_stack();
        }
        else
        {
            char ch;
            if (sscanf(buffer, " %c", &ch) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Operator scan failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("Operator: %c\n", ch);
            dump_stack();
            float op1, op2;
            switch (ch)
            {
            case '+':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f + %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 + op2);
                push(op1 + op2);
                break;
            case '-':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f - %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 - op2);
                push(op1 - op2);
                break;
            case '*':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f * %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 * op2);
                push(op1 * op2);
                break;
            case '/':
                op2 = pop();
                op1 = pop();
                printf("%f / %f = %f\n", op1, op2, op1 / op2);
                push(op1 / op2);
                break;
            case '=':
                op1 = pop();
                printf("Result = %f\n", op1);
                return op1;
                //return pop();
            case 'q':
                printf("Quitting\n");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            default:
                printf("Unexpected operator %c\n", ch);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("EOF or invalid input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define STACK_SIZE 100

_Noreturn void stack_overflow(void);
_Noreturn void stack_underflow(void);

void stack_underflow(void)
{
    printf("\nNot enough operands in expression\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void stack_overflow(void)
{
    printf("\nExpression is too complex\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

float contents[STACK_SIZE];
int top = 0;

void make_empty(void)
{
    top = 0;
}

bool is_empty(void)
{
    return top == 0;
}

bool is_full(void)
{
    return top == STACK_SIZE;
}

void push(float i)
{
    if (is_full())
        stack_overflow();
    else
        contents[top++] = i;
}

float pop(void)
{
    if (is_empty())
        stack_underflow();
    else
        return contents[--top];
}

static void dump_stack(void)
{
    printf("Stack (%d): Top", top);
    for (int i = top; i > 0; i--)
        printf(" %f", contents[i-1]);
    printf(" Bottom\n");
}
```

#### Sample output

```
$ rpn71
Enter an RPN expression: 1 2 3 4 5 + + + + =
NUmber: 1.000000
Stack (1): Top 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 2.000000
Stack (2): Top 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 3.000000
Stack (3): Top 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 4.000000
Stack (4): Top 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
NUmber: 5.000000
Stack (5): Top 5.000000 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
Operator: +
Stack (5): Top 5.000000 4.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
4.000000 + 5.000000 = 9.000000
Operator: +
Stack (4): Top 9.000000 3.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
3.000000 + 9.000000 = 12.000000
Operator: +
Stack (3): Top 12.000000 2.000000 1.000000 Bottom
2.000000 + 12.000000 = 14.000000
Operator: +
Stack (2): Top 14.000000 1.000000 Bottom
1.000000 + 14.000000 = 15.000000
Operator: =
Stack (1): Top 15.000000 Bottom
Result = 15.000000

Value of expression: 15.0000
Stack (0): Top Bottom
Enter an RPN expression: q
Operator: q
Stack (0): Top Bottom
Quitting
$
```

Tested: on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 using GCC 7.2.0, and on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM running on the Mac, using GCC `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`.

Comment: @ JonathanLeffler So, I just compiled and executed your slightly revised rpn61.c and it is still having the same issues. I can't imagine why it would work for you and not for me...

Comment: Me neither.  OK; I identified that I'm working on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and compiling with GCC 7.2.0.  Let's find out what you're using as a platform.  Can you show the debugging printout you got?  Did you have spaces where I showed spaces?  It would be worth printing out the operators and operands as you read them, perhaps.

Comment: @Lyle: see the `rpn67.c` program which I used to reproduce the problem on a Linux VM, and the `rpn71.c` program which contains a workaround for the problem.  There are better ways to do the workaround, but they involve bigger changes to the code.  The workaround code only works sensibly if the RPN operands and operations are space separated.  If they're run together (no spaces), the code treats the whole string as a single operand or operator, and ignores any extra trailing material.  So, entering `1 2+=` would just stack `1` and `2` and not execute any operators.